# flutter run -d windows - Showing error Nuget is not installed

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-windows

When I Run the `flutter run -d windows` command it shows nuget is not installed error. How to solve this in windows.

[nuget installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNZkF.png)

I tried Manual installation of nuget.exe and updated visual studio packages.

I run `flutter doctor -v` cmd no issues found.

Comment: can you show the result of "flutter doctor -v" for more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [NuGet Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference), nuget.exe, provides the full
> extent of NuGet functionality to install, create, publish, and manage
> packages without making any changes to project files.

1. Download the latest [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads), (note: NuGet.exe 5.0 and later require .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later to execute)
2. Move it to a folder in your
   system path, or put it in a folder and add that folder to the system
   path,
3. Restart VSCode or your IDE
4. `flutter run -d windows`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a library/plugin does not support Windows platform actually.

For example, in my case,
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sharing_intent describes to support Windows.  However actually it does not supports Windows.

So that,
I removed flutter.plugin.platforms.windows in pubspec.yaml of flutter_sharing_intent plugin. Then the issue fixed.